# Transaction stuck as "pending" in monero-wallet-cli

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, blockchain, transaction-confirmation

A transaction I made a few hours ago is stuck as "pending", after sending via `monero-wallet-cli`. The transaction has not been picked up in a block yet.

I found this comment on Reddit by /u/gingeropolous: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4qilio/transaction_stuck_at_pending_on_simplewallet_how/d4tazy6

Is there a way to "cancel" the transaction without having to do a blockchain rescan like described in that comment? Also, what steps can I take to prevent a transaction from getting stuck as pending in the future?

Comment: i made this same mistake and find multiple people telling me to flush the txpool with monerod. What the hell is monerod, or monero_cli!!! I don't know where to find those things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can first use the `show_transfers` command in `monero-wallet-cli` to see if your transaction shows there. It should show as "pending". Subsequently, you can use the `flush_txpool` command in `monerod` (the daemon). The wallet will shortly notice this and change the status of the transaction from "pending" to "failed". In order to get the right balance, however, you also need to run the `rescan_spent` command in `monero-wallet-cli`. Note that this minor bug (i.e. not showing the correct balance) is fixed in master currently, but not yet present in the binaries (which you are likely using).

If this doesn't work, you will have to use the `rescan_bc` command in `monero-wallet-cli`.

> Also, what steps can I take to prevent a transaction from getting stuck as pending in the future?

Make sure your daemon is fully synced before sending out a transaction.

**Source:** https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=583449.msg16066918#msg16066918

**EDIT 11/9/2017:** Currently, transactions will drop from the local mempool after 24 hours, which will result in the transaction status changing to `Failed` in `monero-wallet-cli`. Therefore, this answer is not applicable anymore. If, however, your transaction is not relayed and your transaction is time sensitive, you can still apply this answer. You can check if your transaction is relayed by checking the mempool on block explorers like, for instance, [XMRchain](https://xmrchain.net), [MoneroBase](https://monerobase.com/blockexplorer/), or [MoneroBlocks](https://moneroblocks.info).

Comment: Warning: this will do what you want (remove the tx from the "pending" list), but not how you want (the tx will likely get mined at some point so if you have sent again, you'll either pay twice, or the second tx will conflict).