# Missing TX, 24+ hours and XMR is missing :(

Tags: txpool

I sent some XMR 30+ hours ago, the funds are no longer in my CLI wallet and are not showing up at the exchange.

This is with the old version of the wallet, what will happen if it is still stuck during the fork?

Here is the Tx:
84084c82f1f0f58ab1605d61f0c9e35603b445aafd6e80f6d9155b3696efcb22

```
[wallet 4AmGQG]: transfer 47sghzufGhJJDQEbScMCwVBimTuq6L5JiRixD8VeGbpjCTA12noXmi4ZyBZLc99e66NtnKff34fHsGRoyZk3ES1s1V4QVcB 220 2d3a1f8de837ea570f5c6fe21577ce4d3e8bf6454369c99347ffbe6ac636e2b4
Sending 220.000000000000. The transaction fee is 0.025485311456.
Is this okay? (Y/Yes/N/No): y
Money successfully sent, transaction <84084c82f1f0f58ab1605d61f0c9e35603b445aafd6e80f6d9155b3696efcb22>
```

Comment: Also, trying to search the mem pool at xmrchain.net/ the tx does not even seem to be there either.

Comment: This might help http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/transaction-stuck-as-pending-in-simplewallet

Answer (score 2):

If the transaction is not recorded on the blockchain (as suggested from you looking up your tx ID), then the outputs you were trying to spend are still unspent and still owned by your wallet.

Please update your daemon and wallet.  Your daemon may be on a forked-off outdated chain (along with other daemons who failed to update).  And then you may need to let your wallet rescan, once you know you're on the current (actual) chain.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a few weeks ago and was able to resolve it by first deleting the contents my lmdb folder from C:\programdata\bitmonero then running monerod to resync from scratch.

Once the daemon is 100% sync'd open the wallet-cli and rescan_bc.

When this completed I found the funds still resided in my wallet despite having a TX ID before they went "missing."  Hope this helps -- I was only missing 5 not 220!