# How to unlock a PENDING order in Monero Wallet GUI?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Yesterday I tried to send moneros from my Monero wallet GUI (v0.11.1.0).

But they are stucked since. So I updated the wallet to the last version (v0.13.0.3) two hours later.

Unfortunately, this morning they are still not sent with a Blockheight status as "PENDING" and a wallet status "Unlocked balance (waiting for block)".

Blocks seem to be updated:

[image]

But GUI says is "waiting for block":

[image]

Comment: You should also have been able to resolve your issue with the guide I linked fwiw. CLI guide here -> https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/transaction-stuck-as-pending-in-monero-wallet-cli/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by updating to last Monero Wallet version (v0.13.0.3). I was then able to cancel the order using the wallet CLI.